# Do i need parse int all the time in Prisma?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

My prisma model

```
model Todo {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  title String
  content String
  status TodoStatus @default(IN_PROGRESS)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

The api call

```
app.get("/todos/:id", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id); // this line
  const todo = await prisma.todo.findFirst({
    where: { id },
  });

  res.json(todo);
});
```

Do I have to always `parseInt` the id? because by default `req.params` is a string type, and obviously my Todo primary key is int. I don't see any online resources parsing the int and then only passing to the Prisma query, it feels a bit odd to always parsing the req.params.id to int all the time in every api call.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
prisma.todo.findUnique({
    where: { id: +id }
  });
```

Note that you have to specify the field you want to find.

Comment: By the way, isn't supposed your id is unique? So, why to use a findFirst?

Comment: Thanks for that im using `findUnique` now

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Express Query Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-query-parser) to automatically parse strings to valid types.

This would automatically convert query params to the valid type.

Example:

```js
// without this parser
req.query = {a: 'null', b: 'true', c: {d: 'false', e: '3.14'}}

// with this parser
req.query = {a: null, b: true, c: {d: false, e: 3.14}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can use middleware

```
const parseIdMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.parsedId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  next();
};
```

```
// Implement middleware for the specific route
app.get("/todos/:id", parseIdMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  const todo = await prisma.todo.findFirst({
    where: { id: req.parsedId },
  });

  res.json(todo);
});
```